# Classpath in Java/Spring/Maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven

Hi im working on a Spring web MVC project using Java and Maven. I wanted to know how does the "classpath: -file-path-" helps the project to look for the files within it. Is this something done by Spring, Maven or Java?

```java
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
        final ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages"); //classpath for messages files
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName());
        messageSource.setCacheSeconds(5);
        return messageSource;
}
```

Comment: The classpath is a fundamental Java concept.

Comment: @duffymo But `classpath:` resolution for resources is done by the Spring context.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25598077/where-classpath-is-declared-in-spring-mvc-project

Comment: Yes, I get it, but Spring is using well tested Java to resolve that resource.  You could do it yourself, but the Spring folks write better code.